# Reset Tensorflow adam optimizer

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I am performing K-fold cross validation on a neural network model with Tensorflow, so I need to train the model k times.

I would like to know how to reset the state of the tf.train.AdamOptimizer so I can perform a new training after each fold.

Someone suggested:

```
 sess.run(tf.variables_initializer(optimizer.variables()))
```

But this throws the following error:

```
'Operation' object has no attribute 'variables'
```

Comment: How is `optimizer` defined?

Comment: Hey @jdehesa it is defined like this: `tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr).minimize(loss)`

Comment: Right so you should do something like `optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr)` and then `train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)`, then the code you posted should work (you'd have to replace `optimizer` for `train_op` in training loop).

Comment: Thank you for answering @jdehesa . Do you think that it could be better to just do `session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()` at the start of every fold so the weights of the network are reinitialized? Or should I reset the optimizer as you explained too?

Comment: Well if you're doing everything within the same session, yes then I suppose you'd have to reset everything on each fold for cross validation. I would create `init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()` just once beforehand instead of creating new ops in the graph on each fold, but otherwise that sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: Yes, I am doing the K-fold XV in the same session. One last question, `init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()` will reset also the `optimizer` or should I use the commands you wrote in your second comment in addition to the initialization of the global variables. Thanks again @jdehesa

Comment: Yes, a global variables initializer should initialize the optimizer variables too.